# Warehouse managment system on PHP+MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I'm developing warehouse system, that can manage product with different BBDs (best before dates).
So table is quite simple (i'm using MySQL + PHP)

```
ID - PK, Autoincrement
ProductID - FK products
Quantity - positive, if put products to warehouse and negative if take from warehouse
BBD - best before date
OperationDate - DATETIME when operation was created
```

I some goods arrive warehouse, I simply add rows to this table, like

```
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, 500, '2022-02-02', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, 100, '2022-05-15', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2022-10-27', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

But the problem is, when I want to withdraw from warehouse certain amount of exact good.
For example, I have 2 orders (to take FROM warehouse)
First one for `550` pieces, and second one for `70` pieces.

What is the best way and algorythm to calculate, what `Quantity` and what `BBD` will go for each order?
In my example for first order will go:

```
500 pieces with bbd: 2022-02-02
50 pieces with bbd: 2022-05-15
in sql:
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, -500, '2022-02-02', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, -50, '2022-05-15', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

and for second order:

```
50 pieces with bbd: 2022-05-15
20 pieces with bbd: 2022-10-27
in sql:
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, -50, '2022-05-15', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
INSERT INTO warehouse (ProductID, Quantity, BBD, OperationDate) VALUES (1, -20, '2022-10-27', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

Main thing - the worst BBD will left warehouse first.

How should I implement locks/transactions/etc. if there will be many incoming and outgoing orders in parallel?

My first though was, if I can somehow block for exact ProductID even for READ operations when I calculate what BBD to reduce. I tried to use `LOCK TABLES` but it needs to lock every table in query, not so good solution. I tried to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but I'm not sure will it prevent for reading same rows from another sessions.

So, what is the right way to get this?

Comment: pos dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170611/how-to-implement-pessimistic-locking-in-a-php-mysql-web-application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133125/php-mysql-simple-code-to-implement-transaction-commit-rollback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133125/php-mysql-simple-code-to-implement-transaction-commit-rollback

Comment: Where do 550 and 70 come from?

Comment: @Strawberry 550 and 70 - are just quantities for orders FROM warehouse. Just for example.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB (which I assume you are using) supports row locking and you will be able to do that with SELECT... FOR UPDATE.

You can easily test by running 2 different scripts, one trying to update and the other trying to select, the select query will wait until the update is completed.

I am not sure why you are inserting records here, I presume you meant UPDATE.

Comment: But I don't need to update any row. I only need to insert new ones, but with right fields `Quantity` and `BBD` which I can calculate in script.

Comment: insert, because I need to keep history.